# Assign AAD administrative roles to AAD group

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

AAD administrative roles have been only directly assignable to users. They could not be assigned via AAD groups.

Now there is a "Privileged access groups (Preview)" pane in PIM, but I can't find any way to enable a role assignable group in the Azure AD group management. Consequently the list of available AAD groups in PIM is empty. Where can I find this AAD group configuration?

I do find isAssignableToRole as a group property on GET in the Graph API, but PATCH does not work. It looks like an existing AAD group cannot have this flag raised.

The property isAssignableToRole is not available in the Graph API doc.

I am able to create a new AAD security enabled group with the isAssignableToRole flag raised using the Graph API, but the group is still not available in PIM "Privileged access groups (Preview)"

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups
{
    "description": "A test for role assignable groups",
    "displayName": "Test role assignable groups",
    "securityEnabled": true,
    "isAssignableToRole": true,
    "mailEnabled": false,
    "mailNickname": "test-role-assignment2"
}
```

Has Microsoft released a partially implemented feature here? If so, do anyone have an ETA on when it will be ready? I found this feature request flagged by Microsoft as started:
[https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/20227804-enable-pim-role-assignment-by-group-membership#{toggle_previous_statuses}](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/20227804-enable-pim-role-assignment-by-group-membership#%7Btoggle_previous_statuses%7D)

The option to enable assigned AAD roles is not available when creating new group in the portal:
[image: The option to enable assigned AAD roles is not available when creating new group in the portal]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that **Privileged access groups (Preview)** is still in progress. I can see that the data on the page won't be shown because the backend throws an error `"error":{"code":"UnauthorizedAccessException","message":"The tenant has not onboarded to PIM."`, which is not true.

But another related function in Group has been available.

When you create a group with the `isAssignableToRole` flag raised using Microsoft Graph or create a group on Azure Portal like this:

[image]

You will find you could assign Azure AD role to this group.

[image]

Comment: I don't see the "Azure AD roles can be assigned to the group" when creating new group in the portal. I also do not see the "Assigned roles (Preview)" pane in manage group created using Graph API. I have added a screenshot to my question. Do you know how you got those options?

Comment: @ToreOlavKristiansen Oh I'm sorry this feature is also in preview. You need to sign in to this [link](http://aka.ms/assignrolestogroups) with your Azure account to use it. I got this link from Azure support. And I also was told that **Privileged access groups (Preview)** is not available currently.

Comment: Thanks Allen. I see it now.
I discovered that the feature was there all along, but hidden by css class fxs-display-none. I removed this and I could see it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this uservoice is also relevant: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/12938997-azuread-role-delegation-to-groups

they are apparently working on it, but they ran into what appears to be a security design problem, because this means that indirectly anyone who can manage groups would be able to add anyone else to potentially global privileged roles. but it seems like they are working through it hopefully.